# location.replace() and move to a new page when data is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to move to another page after some data is returned from a `$.post()` ?

verifystudent.html:

```
$.post('students/verify.php',
    function(results){
        preventdefault();
        location.replace("verifystudent.html");
        window.location.href = "completed/student_result.html;
    }
```

Basically when the data is received to the `verifystudent.html` it should move to `student_result.html` and when the browser back button is clicked it should avoid going to `verifystudent.html`. How can I do this?

Comment: what data are you posting?

Comment: **1.** No event object on `preventDefault()` **2.** `replace()` expects two params

Comment: what you want to do actually?

Comment: @Alex thanks. calling data from MySQL.

Comment: Once you have gone to the `verifystudent.html` page control the  `window.onbeforeunload` object with your condition. This event will help you to control your navigation once it goes backward

Comment: @Azmatkarim Thanks. When the data is received to the `verifystudent.html` page, the user should moved to `student_result.html`. Then if the user clicks the browser back button, it should skip going to `verifystudent.html` page.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks. IS it possible to add a event object to it? What's the param missing for `replace()`?

Comment: @Becky you didnt answer me what i asked you said what you said above. answer me few questions.1- what is the current page you are on ? 2-are you submitting data to verifystudent.html? 3- why you are redirecting to complete/student_result.html what is its purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this script it prevents browser's back button so use it in verifystudent.html

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    history.pushState(null, null, 'pagename');
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
         history.pushState(null, null, 'pagename');
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to save the state of your application. You can create a key to mark that a student is verified.

Check for this key when the verification page loads and use `location.replace` to change the URL if the student is already verified.

Also read [this](http://www.irt.org/script/311.htm) article about preventing users from going to the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question "*and when the browser back is clicked it should avoid going to verifystudent.html*"

I was searching for the same question and I found following code on a site. Thought to share it here:

```
function noBack()
{
   window.history.forward()
}
noBack();
window.onload = noBack;
window.onpageshow = function(evt){ if(evt.persisted) noBack(); }
window.onunload = function(){ void(0); }
```

However as noted by number of developers, this is never a good practice and should be avoided for all reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JQuery `navigation` event on `verifystudent.html` to send the user to the desired page

```
 $(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
      var direction = data.state.direction;
      if (direction == 'back') {
         window.location.href = "completed/student_result.html;
      }
}
```